# Make current git working copy equivalent to past commit

Tags: git, git-reset

Given a simple git repo where my branch is currently set to commit `C`:

```
A--B--C
```

I want to "reset" my local copy index of staged/unstaged changes to be the same as `A`.

But, and this is the key, I do not want to change the checked out branch pointer. I do not want to reset back to `A`. I want the current uncommitted changes and/or next commit `D` to be equivalent to `A` while preserving the previous history of commits.

```
A--B--C--D
         ^ same as A
```

So the local index should show the diff, on top of `C`, to change the repo back to the `A` state. If I then commit that change, it should create a new commit `D` that is equivalent to `A`.

How can this be done using git?

If this has already been asked, please alert me to duplicates. My ability to search for this behavior is failing me.

Comment: If you can accept history of D to be different with A, you can check `git revert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat. Here's one fairly simple approach:

```
git reset --hard A # (A)
git reset --soft C # (A-B-C) but with the reverse of B and C staged
git commit -m "Revert back to A" # (A-B-C-D)
```

Now a compare between A and D should yield no changes.

Comment: That's a good straightforward way to do it. I'd ideally like to find a way using only the target SHA, not manually reverting multiple intermediate commits.

Comment: @pkamb I think I got closer to what you're envisioning with Method #2.

Comment: That second method is great, and probably what I'll end up using going forward. What do you think about editing your question to remove Method 1? We could edit some of your `revert` answer into ramwin's.

Comment: @pkamb good suggestion. I'll let you and/or ramwin update the other answer as desired. Perhaps it would be nice to show what I had as it's easy to understand, and then the more concise (and efficient) version of it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a shortcut method using one of Git's so-called plumbing commands: `git read-tree`.  Run `git read-tree -u hash-or-other-commit-specifier` at the appropriate time, and you now have in Git's index and your working tree a "clean" copy of the files from the specified commit hash.

The phrase "appropriate time" above means: don't do this when you have uncommitted work.  If `git status` says `nothing to commit, working tree clean` you're in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

```
# revert back to commit A
git revert -n/--no-commit HEAD^^...HEAD

# make a commit D that is same as commit A
git commit -m 'revert to A'
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain what the `-n/--no-commit HEAD^^...HEAD` bit does?

Comment: Ooh. I like this. My answer is the manual version of this. @pkamb this is reverting a range of commits all in one command. Normally this command would still create a commit for each revert, but with --no-commit (or -n) it won't commit each one, so it will leave the entire set of reverts staged and ready to be committed in one shot. (No rebase needed like in my answer.)

Comment: the meaning of `-n` or `--no-commit` was answered by @TTT clearly.  The meaning of `HEAD^^...HEAD` means I want to revert the commit from `HEAD^^` to `HEAD`. `HEAD` is the lastest commit, `HEAD^` is the commit before the latest commit and `HEAD^^` is the commit before the commit before the latest commit :).